# Change css class of anchor tag by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a list in my page like this,

```
 <ul id="breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumbs-two">
        <li><a href="#" class="current"  id="a1">Step1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"  id="a2">Step2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"  id="a3">Step3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"  id="a4">Step4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"  id="a5">Complete</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Now I want to add some css class to a tag on click of some link button.

css class :

```
 .breadcrumbs-two .current
    {
        background: #99db76;
    }

    .breadcrumbs-two .current, .breadcrumbs-two .current:after
    {
        border-left-color: #99db76;
    }

    .breadcrumbs-two .current, .breadcrumbs-two .current:before
    {
        border-color: #99db76 #99db76 #99db76 transparent;
    }
```

How can I do this?

I have tried with this

```
function addClass(dis) {
        dis.className += "current";
    }

 <li><a href="javascript:addClass(this)"  id="a1">Step1</a></li>

  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="addClass('a1')">Done</asp:LinkButton>
```

But its not working.

Please someone help me.

Thanks in Advance
Gulrej

Answer (score 2):

If your question is a navigation menu, you might try this one for this is what I did with my current project now.

```
 $('.breadcrumbs-two li a').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().children('li').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
 });
```

Upon clicking one link, it will remove selected links' css and put `.current` class to newly clicked or selected link.

---

I thought the `<li>` tags are the one that is going to be clicked. Maybe you can try this one:

```
$.fn.breadcrumb = function( content, title ){
    $(this).parent().parent().children('li').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
};

$('#LinkButton1').click(function(){
    $(this).breadcrumb();
});
```

Comment: How will I call this function in my LinkButton event? my link button is <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Done</asp:LinkButton>

Comment: check updated function above and try it, for i really though li tags are the one that is going to be clicked

Answer (score 1):

You can give different colors and css based on active,visited,hover,link,etc..

```
a {
    outline: 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:link {
    color: #0099FF;
}

a:visited {
    color: #0099FF;
}

a:hover {
    color: #FFFF00;
}

a:active {
    color: #33FF66;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your anchor tag href

```
javascript:addClass(this)
```

Define this function in javascript

```
function addClass(dis)
{
   dis.className = dis.className + ' yourclass';
}
```

Comment: I want to add the CSS on click of the link button. So how my javascript will work.

Comment: When you will click the link, addClass function will be called

Comment: <a href="javascript:addClass(this)" class="current"  id="a1">Step1</a>

Comment: I have added like this, <li><a href="javascript:addClass(this)"  id="a1">Step1</a></li> and  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="addClass('a1')">Done</asp:LinkButton> but the css is not reflecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.breadcrumbs-two a').click(function(){

        $('.breadcrumbs-two a').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

    })
})
```

Comment: Hi Sangram, Thanks for the help. One doubt, I need to call this in ancor tag ?

Comment: it automaticaly bind event to anchor tag after page load